# Add-ins not Opening for Non-Organizational Accounts in Centralized Deployment

Tags: ms-word, azure-active-directory, office365, ms-office, office-addins

I am currently working on a project where I am embedding add-ins into a Word document using the OpenXML SDK. The add-ins are intended to provide additional functionality to users within an organizational environment. The deployment of these add-ins is done centrally on Centralized deployment for everyone to ensure uniform access across the organization.

The problem I am encountering is that the add-ins are not opening up for users who have non-organizational accounts, such as Gmail, Yahoo, or Hotmail. However, the add-ins work perfectly fine for organizational users with valid credentials.
User Principal name : user_gmail.com#EXT#@organizationemail.onmicrosoft.com

User type : Guest
Identities : google.com

Error message: You don't have permission to use this add-in. Contact your system administrator to request access.

Here are some specific details about the setup and the issue:

Deployment: The add-ins are deployed using centralized deployment in our organization. The deployment process doesn't raise any errors or issues, and it appears that the add-ins are successfully deployed.

Access Scope: The add-ins are intended to be available to all users, regardless of whether they have organizational or non-organizational accounts. However, non-organizational users seem to be unable to access the add-ins.

Authentication: The add-ins do not require any specific authentication with organizational credentials. They should ideally open for all users without any additional login.

Permissions: As far as I can tell, the add-ins do not access any sensitive data or require special permissions that could restrict access for non-organizational accounts.

Testing: To isolate the issue, I have tested the add-ins with several non-organizational accounts, and the problem is consistently reproducible. The add-ins simply fail to open without any clear error message.

Error Handling: I have implemented error handling mechanisms in the add-ins, but no errors are being logged or shown when the add-ins fail to open for non-organizational users.

I am seeking assistance from the community to understand why the add-ins are not accessible to non-organizational accounts and to find a solution to make them available for all users. Any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if you require additional information or if there are specific steps I can take to further diagnose the issue. Thank you in advance for your help!